# How can I show that this product is equal to a product of Gamma functions?

Tags: gamma-function, products

$\prod_{n=0}^{x-1}\left( 1+\frac{a}{an+b}\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\Gamma\left(x+\frac{a+b}{b}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b}{b}\right)\Gamma\left(x+\frac{a}{b}\right)}$

I found this equality through maple and it is also equal to $\frac{b}{a}x+1$ but what I'm interested in is how can one derive this equality and what is the relation between products like these and the Gamma function?

I need to simplify a similar expression that maple can't simplify, so if I can understand how to derive this, I may be able to simplify the more difficult expressions.

This expression came up in solving for the hypergeometric polynomials from it's difference equation. Multiplying by $\frac{a}{b}$ gives the first polynomial in the sequence. However I don't think it is related to simplifying the product in this way

Comment: Try rewriting the term in parentheses on the left as a quotient; the result follows from the properties of the gamma function naturally.

Comment: I apologize, but I wasn't able to see the connection with the gamma function. The only simplification I can see is getting straight to $\frac{bx}{a}+1$. Could you tell me the property I might be missing? Thank you

Comment: $x = \frac{\Gamma(x + 1)}{\Gamma(x)}$

Comment: Ah ok that actually was pretty easy. I thought maple had used some identity relating to the product, but this just seems like the simplified form made a little more complicated.